# add hanging indent to list of tables

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, indentation, front-matter

How can I adjust the entries in the List of Tables (in a book document class) so that each entry has a hanging indent? I'd prefer not to use a package if possible, but will accept answers that rely on packages as well.

By default, the List of Tables is formatted like this:

```
1.1 This is a really long table caption that will wrap lines.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque ut dui quis 
    massa laoreet venenatis.
1.1 This is a really long table caption that will wrap lines.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque ut dui quis 
    massa laoreet venenatis.
```

I'd like it to look something like this:

```
1.1 This is a really long table caption that will wrap lines.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque ut dui 
      massa laoreet venenatis.
1.1 This is a really long table caption that will wrap lines.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque ut dui 
      massa laoreet venenatis.
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Which document class are you using? What effect of hanging indent do you expect?

Comment: Thanks @muzimuzhiZ ! I've updated the original question.

Comment: @campa I mentioned that it's a book document class.

Comment: Ups, sorry, I missed that.

Comment: It is recommended to provide a specific and complete example (also called [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)), since different settings you use may lead to/require different solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example using `tocloft` package which adds an extra 2em hanging indent to the first line of list-of entries of tables. For more info, check the package manual of [`tocloft`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tocloft/tocloft.pdf).

```tex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\cfttabnumwidth}{4.3em} % before: 2.3em
\renewcommand{\cfttabaftersnumb}{\hspace*{-2em}}

\begin{document}
\listoftables

\chapter{title}
\begin{table}
  \caption{\lipsum[2]}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]